# How do I add a dialog (from a resource file) to a tab

Tags: c, winapi, tabs

I have been tasked with a project to make some modifications to the user interface of a particular program. Part of this is that I am adding more information to a particular dialog box. To make it look better I thought that having a tabbed interface would work better. Currently all layouts in this program are done in a resource (.rc) file.

I have been reading up on dialogs with tabs, and I believe this is done by creating a dialog layout for each tab (with no border and 'child' style), and then displaying the layout depending on which tab is selected. My problem is that I have been unable to find any good documentation/examples on how to actually do this.

Some Code:

```
//create the main dialog from WndProc - no problem here
DialogBox(hInst, (char*)IDD_DIALOG_MAIN, hWnd, MainDlgProc);
```

Dialog Code:

```
HWND hTab;

BOOL CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCITEM titem;

    switch (Message)    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            //create tab control
            //I didn't use a tabcontrol in the resource file because I could not figure out how to get a handle for it

            hTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,
                          30, 30, 400, 550, hDlg,(HMENU) ID_TABCTRL, hInst, NULL);

            //add a couple of tabs
            titem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
            titem.pszText = "Tab1";
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 0, &titem);

            titem.pszText = "Tab2";
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 1, &titem);

            //add content to tabs using dialog resource IDs???
            //Obviously this doesn't work. It doesn't even point to which tab the content should be on
            //CreateDialog(hInst,IDD_DIALOG_MAIN_TAB1, hTab, Tab1DlgProc);
            //CreateDialog(hInst,IDD_DIALOG_MAIN_TAB2, hTab, Tab2DlgProc);
            //EDIT: See my answer below for how I placed the dialogs in the tabs


            //etc....
```

Any suggestions on where I can read up a bit more on this kind of stuff would be appreciated. Also, if anything in my approach seems completely wrong feel free to tell me why that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found this page: [How to Create a Tabbed Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From this I learned to load the dialog resource for each tab using code similar to:

```
DLGTEMPLATEEX *apRes[N_TABS];    
apRes[0] = DoLockDlgRes(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FIRSTDLG));
apRes[1] = DoLockDlgRes(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SECONDDLG));
```

With

```
DLGTEMPLATEEX* DoLockDlgRes(LPCTSTR lpszResName) 
{ 
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, lpszResName, RT_DIALOG); 

    // Note that g_hInst is the global instance handle
    HGLOBAL hglb = LoadResource(g_hInst, hrsrc);  
    return (DLGTEMPLATEEX *) LockResource(hglb); 
}
```

Then the dialogs are loaded using

```
int currentSlectedTabIndex = 0;
HWND hSelectedTab;

VOID OnSelChanged(HWND hDlg)
{
    //get tab control
    HWND hTab = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TAB1);

    // Get the index of the selected tab.
    currentTabIndex = TabCtrl_GetCurSel(hTab);

    // Destroy the current child dialog box, if any.
    if (hSelectedTab != NULL)
        DestroyWindow(hSelectedTab);

    // Create the new child dialog box
    hSelectedTab = CreateDialogIndirect(hInst, apRes[currentTabIndex], hDlg, TabDlgProc);

    return;
}
```

With `TabDlgProc` being responsible for sizing and positioning the dialog in the tab.
To check if the tab has been switched I check for a WM_NOTIFY message with TCN_SELCHANGE

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    switch ( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code ) {
    case TCN_SELCHANGE:
        OnSelChanged(hDlg); //change tab
        break;
    }

    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. After you create the child dialogs you have to size and position them on the tab control. You can use MoveWindow for that.

BTW, if the tab control is placed in the resource file you can get its handle with GetDlgItem(ID).

Comment: Thanks for the point about GetDlgItem. Not sure why I didn't come across that.

Answer (score 0):

here is DLGTEMPLATEEX struct

```
#define sz_Or_Ord WORD
#define titleLen 30
#define stringLen 30
typedef struct {
    WORD      dlgVer;
    WORD      signature;
    DWORD     helpID;
    DWORD     exStyle;
    DWORD     style;
    WORD      cDlgItems;
    short     x;
    short     y;
    short     cx;
    short     cy;
    sz_Or_Ord menu;
    sz_Or_Ord windowClass;
    WCHAR     title[titleLen];
    WORD      pointsize;
    WORD      weight;
    BYTE      italic;
    BYTE      charset;
    WCHAR     typeface[stringLen];
} DLGTEMPLATEEX;
```